# How do I resize an animated GIF using nearest-neighbor interpolation?

Tags: macos, image-editing, gif

I'd like to resize an animated GIF image of some pixel art.

I'm on macOS and am comfortable with the command-line.

Comment: Animated GIF. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used [Gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) to do this. You can install it with homebrew.

```
brew install gifsicle
```

Then, to resize an image using nearest-neighbor interpolation, run

```
gifsicle --resize 512x512 --resize-method sample doodle002.gif > doodle002-big.gif
```

From the [manual](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html) for the `--resize-method` parameter:

> The ‘sample’ method is a point sampler. Each pixel position in the
>   output image maps to exactly one pixel position in the input, so when
>   shrinking, full rows and columns from the input are dropped.

Even though this doesn't explicitly say "nearest-neighbor interpolation" the described method sounds exactly like nearest-neighbor.

Comment: oop, typo in `gifscicle` for the copy-pasters out there

Comment: @andrewxhill Thanks! I've updated the brew command.